# Why does clojurescript call some js functions with "-" and others not?

Tags: clojurescript

Some functions in clojurescript start with a hyphen `-` like `.-onload` in`js/window` context or `.-fillstyle` in canvas context while others like `.getElementById` do not start with a `-`hyphen. Why is this peculiarity? What am i missing here?

Comment: "onLoad" is a property where we can *store* a function to be invoked "on load". Yes, it can get confusing, especially since both JS and CLJS are Lisp-1s where the syntax allows properties to be called!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe the .- signifies that you’re accessing a property. Read more about js-interop here http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop